# Does Amazon MQ support rabbitmq-consistent-hash-exchange

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, amazon-mq

Does the RabbitMQ variant of Amazon MQ support [rabbitmq-consistent-hash-exchange](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-consistent-hash-exchange)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is supported on Amazon MQ as of July 6, 2021:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/07/amazon-mq-for-rabbitmq-now-supports-the-consistent-hash-exchange-type/

Answer (score 0):

**Here's the old, now obsolete answer** (See [accepted answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1069396/124382) for latest updates):

No. The [FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/faqs/) state this:

> Amazon MQ for RabbitMQ includes the management, shovel, and federation plugins on all brokers.

And this:

> If you want greater control in order to customize features and configurations or to use custom plugins, you may want to consider installing and running your message broker on Amazon EC2 directly.